# how to have a better control over Kuberenetes default load balancing strategy?

Tags: java, kubernetes, postman, load-balancing, rate-limiting

So my K8's deployment has been scaled up to 5 pods and, it is masked by a single URL.(K8's service)

Each of the pod running has only one API exposed and it also only accepts one request at a time. This is configured this way because single request will take around 20 minutes to complete the load and cannot be changed.
Now the default way i use the API is, i open 5 tabs in postman tool, load different necessary parameters and i hit the endpoint continously one by one until all 5 pods are running all of my different loads. Now if a same request goes to a pod which is alreading running a load, it simply rejects by stating "RETRY", and then i again keep hitting request until one of the pods accepts it.

Im thinking of building a client app, replacing the postman manual effort, where the client app will hit the api with a timeout of 10 seconds, and in the next 10 seconds if it does not get "RETRY", that means a pod has currently accepted this request, else again hit the endpoint until i dont get "RETRY"

I wanted to know if there is a better way of handling this scenario.

I tried writing a script that hits the URL with a timeout of 10 seconds, within the 10 seconds if i get a response, i would assume that this request needs to be retried, if even after 10 seconds i dont get a response, i assume that a pod is running my request and i move on to other requests.

Comment: When you say "API", what technology are you using here?  My experience with HTTP has generally been that _some_ layer in the stack is going to impose a 60-second timeout, and it's better to aim for individual HTTP calls to be under 1 second if possible.  The setup you're describing here sounds like a queueing system like RabbitMQ might be a better match?

Comment: Is your issue resolved?if yes, can you post the procedure you've followed as Solution and accept it for the greater visibility of community